# Biblioteca highcharts não mostra dados

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código em PHP, este código faz com que busque os dados do MySQL e mostre em um gráfico na visualização em HTML.

O problema é que os dados não são mostrados na tela para visualização do usuário final.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>       
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>        
</head>    
<body>    
<?php   
//error_reporting('0');    
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error connecting to server');
mysql_select_db("financeapp", $con); 

$SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM highcharts";

$result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
$data1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   $data1[] = $row['datehigh'];
}

$result2 = mysql_query($SQL1);
$data2 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
   $data2[] = hexdec($row['conteudo']);
}    
?>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
             renderTo: 'container',
             type: 'line'
          },    
        title:  {
                    text: 'Comming Data'
                },    
        xAxis:  {
                    categories: ['<?php echo join($data1, "','") ?>'],
                },   
        yAxis:  {
                    min:0,   
                },   
        legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 50,
                    y: 35,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                },   
        plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                                    borderWidth: 0
                                }
                    },    
        series: [   {
                        name: 'Data',
                        data: ['<?php echo join($data2, "','") ?>'],
                       // pointStart: 0
                        //pointInterval
                    },
                ]
    });
});
</script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: pode postar o codigo-fonte da pagina gerada apos o processamento do seu script PHP? pode ser que o conteúdo retornado da sua consulta esteja gerando o seu problema, mas como obviamente não tenho acesso a sua base de dados, não consigo testar para confirmar

Comment: Vale uma lida neste tópico da central de ajuda: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Procure sempre criar um exemplo simples e incluí-lo no próprio corpo da pergunta.

Comment: Agradeço pelas informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinha alguns erros no seu código, por exemplo, [join](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.join.php), sendo dessa forma a separação é o primeiro parâmetro e o array o segundo `join(',', $data1)`, no seu código estava invertido.

Outro fator era o Gráfico que tem dados que deverão ficar entre aspas simples (`xAxis:  { categories: ['<?php echo join("','", $data1) ?>'],},`) e os valores sem aspas (`series: [{ name: 'Data', data: [<?php echo join(',',$data2) ?>]`), no PHP o while só precisa ser executado uma vez para preencher os dois arrays (`$data1`,`$data2`);

*Obs: Não utilize mysql_, porque, ele é obsoleto nas novas versões do PHP, utilize [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) ou [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)*

**Segue o exemplo funcional:**

**Código**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>      
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
</head> 
<body> 
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error connecting to server');
       mysql_select_db("financeapp", $con);           
       $SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM highcharts";

       $result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
       $data1 = array();
       $data2 = array();
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
           $data1[] = $row['datehigh'];
           $data2[] = hexdec($row['conteudo']);
       } 
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
             renderTo: 'container',
             type: 'line'
          }, 
        title:  { text: 'Comming Data' }, 
        xAxis:  { categories: ['<?php echo join("','", $data1) ?>'],}, 
        yAxis:  { min:0, }, 
        legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 50,
                    y: 35,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                }, 
        plotOptions: { column: { pointPadding: 0.2, borderWidth: 0 }}, 
        series: [{ name: 'Data', data: [<?php echo join(',',$data2) ?>],
                       // pointStart: 0
                        //pointInterval
                    },]
    });
});
</script> 
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**A tabela que eu criei como exemplo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado Obtido:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código Html gerado pelo navegador**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>      
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
             renderTo: 'container',
             type: 'line'
          }, 
        title:  { text: 'Comming Data' }, 
        xAxis:  { categories: ['1','2','3','4','5'],}, 
        yAxis:  { min:0, }, 
        legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 50,
                    y: 35,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                }, 
        plotOptions: { column: { pointPadding: 0.2, borderWidth: 0 }}, 
        series: [{ name: 'Data', data: [16,32,48,64,80],
                       // pointStart: 0
                        //pointInterval
                    },]
    });
});
</script> 
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Realmente está funcionando bem. estou tentando implementa-lo para funcionar com o comando de data do mysql. eu tenho a data 01/02/14 e nela foi obtido o valor 50 e 02/02/14 foi obtido o valor 100, mais o a questão é que é demostrado outro valores completamente diferentes na visualização já renderizada. Aqui está a minha tabela em .sql: http://pastebin.com/TgUTEjtt e uma imagem onde ocorre o valor demostrado incorretamente: http://i.imgur.com/ITGj9ox.png

Comment: editei minha pergunta ;)

Comment: então estou utilizando o código que você repassou o valor é demostrado mais estou utilizando o campo do mysql date para gerar um valor para cada data inserida pelo usuário. o valor que está hospedado no mysql é um e na visualização do gráfico é demostrado outro valor completamente diferente.

Comment: Tentei remover os dados do banco de dados, inseri datas aleatórias. mais o erro persiste continua o mesmo.

Comment: Não é informado nenhum erro. os dados estão aparecendo na renderização mais não o valor correto do banco de dados. aqui esta o formato do meu banco de dados: http://i.imgur.com/fuCiYux.png já na tabela conteúdo. eu tenho os valores: 500 e 250 mais são demostrados valores completamente diferentes: http://i.imgur.com/g83TF2E.png

Comment: Vai la na rotina e no $date2 tem hexdec retire pode ser isso?

Comment: O problema era realmente este, obrigado pela ajuda.