# Array em JavaScript não funciona no gráfico pie highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
var conteudodoGrafico = new Array();//cris gráfico
                for(x in data['linha']) {

                     conteudodoGrafico.push('["'+data['linha'][x].nome+'", '+   data['linha'][x].enviado+']'); //cris grafico
}


conteudodoGrafico = ("[ " +conteudodoGrafico+ " ]");
var data_str = JSON.stringify(conteudodoGrafico);

    $('#graficoPizza').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Gráfico SMS'
        },
        subtitle: {
                text: 'Relatório'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }
            }
        },
       series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Quantidade enviados',
                data: JSON.parse(data_str)
              }]
    });
alert(JSON.parse(data_str));
```

no alert `JSON.parse(data_str)` do navegador está imprimindo assim:

```
[
    ["AIRPLAN", 2476],
    ["IMPACTO INFORMATICA E TECNOLOGIA", 0],
    ["LINCE ENTREGAS RAPIDAS", 0],
    ["AFRANIO FERREIRA FÉLIX", 1],
    ["FRISSON COMUNICAÇAO E MARKETING LTDA", 0],
    ["GEDALYAS MENEZES DOS SANTOS", 0]
]
```

[image: Imagem de amostra de como fica o conteudo do grafico com esses valores passados por variavel]

Comment: Aqui no SOpt tem muitas resposta sobre uma foi a minha: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13526/biblioteca-highcharts-nao-mostra-dados/13535#13535

Comment: Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar no código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Veja na [Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Tentei reproduzir seu código e consegui exibir o gráfico sem problema nenhum http://jsfiddle.net/Hg6TT/

Comment: O problema é que se você copiar o que está dentro do array ( no alert de exmplo ) da certo mais colocando no data: JSON.parse(data_str) não da segue imagem como fica...

Comment: Tente reproduzir seu erro no **http://jsfiddle.net**, pegue seu `jSon` e dê o parse nele, e edite sua pergunta inserindo o link do *jsfidle*, ou poste seu `jSon` completo para podermos tentar reproduzir o erro.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro para exibi-lo, se puder me ajudar conectando via teamviwer segue id: 451 586 561  senha: 5aj82f   obrigado!!!

Comment: dê um console.log(data_str) e posta aqui o resultado

Comment: é muito complicado colocar o código todo aqui por que e muito grande e você não vai entender nada so queria saber como o gráfico ( data: ) tem quer ser feito exemplo: assim funciona - data: [["AIRPLAN", 2476]]   e assim não funciona - data: JSON.parse(data_str) sendo que é a mesma coisa entende?

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14541/discussion-between-cristiano-and-erlon-charles)

Comment: var conteudodoGrafico = new Array();//cris gráfico
    for(x in data['linha']) {
      conteudodoGrafico.push('["'+data['linha'][x].nome+'", '+   data['linha'][x].enviado+']');                      conteudodoGrafico = ("[ " +conteudodoGrafico+ " ]");
var data_str = JSON.stringify(conteudodoGrafico);

Answer (score 1):

//consegui resolver assim:
var conteudodoGrafico = new Array()
  for(x in data['linha']) {
     conteudodoGrafico.push('["'+data['linha'][x].nome+'",'+   data['linha'][x].enviado+']');
  }

conteudodoGrafico2 = ("[ " +conteudodoGrafico+ " ]");

```
var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'graficoPizza',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Gráfico SMS'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Relatório de porcentagem de Enviados'
                },
                 tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 1
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Quantidade enviados',
                    data: JSON.parse(conteudodoGrafico2)
                }]
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Já que você está utilizando jQuery para gerar o gráfico, utilize-o também para fazer o *parse* do jSon.

seu *series* ficará assim:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Quantidade enviados',
    data: jQuery.parseJSON(data_str)
}]
```

Pelo o q eu consegui reproduzir o seu *data* ainda estava recebendo uma *string* no lugar de um *array* como é possível verificar na reprodução do erro no 

### jsfiddle